# Drawing arcs with colors and texts

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I wanted to draw an arc similar to this one but with some differentiates,

[Okla's speed test app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV0xk.jpg)

I have drawn 2 arcs similar to the one that's above, but i am getting some hardly time in adding colors like the image above and also i wanted to add texts like this one :

[My imagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxTo8.jpg)

Here's the code :

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
android:width="300dp"
android:height="300dp"
android:viewportWidth="300.0"
android:viewportHeight="300.0">


 <!-- Inner circle -->
<path
    android:pathData="M55,150 A50,50 0 1 1 245,150"
    android:strokeColor="@android:color/white"
    android:strokeWidth="3"/>

    <!-- Outer circle -->
    <path android:pathData="M30,160 A50,55 0 1 1 270,160"
        android:strokeColor="@android:color/white"
        android:strokeWidth="3"/>

    <!-- Left line -->
    <path android:pathData="M29,160 L55,150"
        android:strokeColor="@android:color/white"
        android:strokeWidth="3"/>

    <!-- Right line -->
    <path
        android:pathData="M243,150 L270,159"
        android:strokeColor="@android:color/white"
        android:strokeWidth="3"/>
```

And here's the circle :

[Android preview from the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbeBh.png)

So my questions is about :

- How can i add the numbers like the image above, between the 2 arcs stroke.
- Also how can i add colors like okla image, between the 2 arcs stroke.

I will be appreciate if someone tried to help.

Comment: Why not use an "image" as background with the numbers at the correct position? Is probably what OOKLA do.

Comment: Images would take too much space since the app would be for different screen sizes, So anyway how he did the animation of the color if it's just an image.

Comment: maybe a GIF with a drawed arc by a timer... idk just a suggestion